# Remove ability to Permanently delete an image from the Media Library

Tags: customization

I'm using the following code to display the WP Editor on the front end page:

```
$content = '';
$editor_id = 'mycustomeditor';
wp_editor( $content, $editor_id );
```

When a user clicks on an image in the Media Library I would like to take away the ability to Permanently delete the image.

I unset some options for the Media Uploader already with the following code:

```
function member_media_view_strings( $strings ) {
    unset( $string['uploadImagesTitle'] );
    unset( $strings['createGalleryTitle'] );

    return $strings;
}
add_filter( 'media_view_strings', 'member_media_view_strings', 99 );
```

I know there is a `warnDelete` string but nothing that actually removes that link. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Are your users anonymous or registered in your WP install?

Comment: @Rarst to upload photos they would need to be a registered user and would have a username in the DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25894288/wordpress-remove-attachment-fields

I actually just added the following in my CSS file to basically remove the links at all times:

```
.media-sidebar .details .edit-attachment {
    display: none;
}
.media-sidebar .details .delete-attachment {
    display: none;
}
```

To actually show this within the admin section I actually show it by using the following code:

```
foreach( array( 'post.php', 'post-new.php' ) as $hook )
    add_action( "admin_print_styles-$hook", 'admin_styles_so_25894288');

function admin_styles_so_25894288() {
    global $typenow;
    if( 'post' !== $typenow )
        return;
    ?>
    <style>
        .media-sidebar .details .delete-attachment
        { 
            display: block; 
        }
        .media-sidebar .details .edit-attachment
        { 
            display: block; 
        }
    </style>
    <?php

}
```

This is tested in Wordpress 4.0.

Answer (score 2):

That link is hard-coded in `/wp-includes/media-template.php` ~ln 526.  Since it can't be removed via apply_filters, you could probably use a small js script like `$('a.delete-attachment').remove();`  to remove the link.

Comment: This doesn't work because the element isn't added to the DOM yet when the code runs for the remove so it doesn't remove it. I tried to do the following: `$('a.delete-attachment').click(function (e){ alert('it is clicked'); e.preventDefault(); });` which doesn't work either. This is because my JS file isn't loaded from the admin section and is only enqueued from my functions.php file. How can I have this loaded even in the admin section?

Comment: For some reason on the front end the editor was being weird and wouldn't let me click on the image. I was testing with the admin panel but that wasn't obviously my question

Comment: I was finally able to test this and the small script isn't working. I can still click on the link and it tries to delete the image. Since it looks like the `media-template.php` file adds this after the dom is loaded I tried to change my code to use `on` with jquery but the link is still clickable and tries to delete the image: `$( 'a.delete-attachment' ).on( 'click', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); alert( 'it is in here' ); });`